# Make a pandas dataframe from netcdf4 data where one dimension is the columns and another dimension is the rows for a variable assigned to both dims

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf4

I have a large netcdf4 dataset that I would like to turn into a .csv with a variable's dimensions assigned to each column and row. I have attached what the netcdf4 file contains below. My desire is to populate a matrix with the variable 'q' and have the rows of the dataframe associated with the x-dimension and to populate columns with the associated y-dimension. I am quite new to working with multivariate data, any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
import xarray as xr    
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = xr.open_dataset("goa_discharge_time_series_cfsr_19790901_20140831.nc", decode_times=False)
print(ds)
print(ds['q'].units)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 12784, x: 12784, x_grid: 1810, y: 14052, y_grid: 900)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) float64 7.231e+05 7.231e+05 ... 7.358e+05 7.358e+05
Dimensions without coordinates: x, x_grid, y, y_grid
Data variables:
    q          (y, x) float64 ...
    lon        (y) float64 ...
    lat        (y) float64 ...
    wshed_id   (y) float64 ...
    lon_grid   (y_grid, x_grid) float64 ...
    lat_grid   (y_grid, x_grid) float64 ...
    topo_grid  (y_grid, x_grid) float64 ...
    strm_grid  (y_grid, x_grid) float64 ...
    info       float32 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to address this issue and wanted to post it here in case anyone else needed this in their process.

```
q = ds['q'].to_series()
q_grid = q.unstack(level=0)
q_grid

y   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 14042   14043   14044   14045   14046   14047   14048   14049   14050   14051
x                                                                                   
0   0.011218    0.011234    0.124699    0.033868    0.104342    0.011323    0.097676    0.011341    0.011360    0.011239    ... 0.023286    0.088536    0.017485    0.011656    0.003322    0.105294    0.017476    0.415685    0.076552    0.588808
1   0.011763    0.011774    0.098714    0.035199    0.083115    0.011838    0.076562    0.011852    0.011865    0.011778    ... 0.024269    0.090955    0.018267    0.012213    0.002351    0.108400    0.018260    0.415926    0.078872    0.590938
2   0.012133    0.012139    0.071252    0.036302    0.064886    0.012188    0.058361    0.012198    0.012209    0.012145    ... 0.024883    0.093083    0.018692    0.012485    0.001664    0.111179    0.018697    0.419632    0.080774    0.598520
3   0.012243    0.012247    0.050603    0.036720    0.051499    0.012284    0.045024    0.012293    0.012304    0.012251    ... 0.025048    0.093847    0.018772    0.012526    0.001178    0.112293    0.018791    0.421400    0.081411    0.604079
4   0.012184    0.012186    0.035837    0.036613    0.041794    0.012217    0.035415    0.012224    0.012238    0.012187    ... 0.024886    0.093390    0.018619    0.012416    0.000834    0.111910    0.018648    0.419441    0.080980    0.604535
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
12779   0.015584    0.015738    0.219197    0.047471    0.174384    0.015971    0.163903    0.015964    0.016043    0.015892    ... 0.021944    0.084094    0.016731    0.011168    0.024425    0.099991    0.016644    0.397708    0.072412    0.536850
12780   0.016257    0.016424    0.169907    0.049275    0.136432    0.016686    0.126396    0.016686    0.016765    0.016563    ... 0.022074    0.084939    0.016838    0.011233    0.017303    0.100947    0.016747    0.399326    0.073044    0.544018
12781   0.016725    0.016902    0.122211    0.050773    0.105050    0.017190    0.095308    0.017196    0.017275    0.017027    ... 0.022024    0.084972    0.016785    0.011194    0.036648    0.100980    0.016703    0.405954    0.073027    0.547534
12782   0.016886    0.017071    0.086743    0.051434    0.082206    0.017377    0.072707    0.017389    0.017470    0.017185    ... 0.022392    0.086223    0.017099    0.011416    0.027093    0.102429    0.017011    0.411336    0.074132    0.553551
12783   0.016842    0.017032    0.061425    0.051437    0.065765    0.017351    0.056508    0.017368    0.017451    0.017136    ... 0.022564    0.087045    0.017227    0.011496    0.019292    0.103380    0.017139    0.413126    0.074813    0.559262
```